# Xamarin.Form Previewer : An Exception occurred while rendering the control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, styles

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to learn about `<Style>` tag. I have problem When I start adding  tag on `App.xaml` file,warning message appear.I don't know what mistake that i make. Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

**Error Message**

[image]

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="blueColor">#1E90FF</Color>
            <Color x:Key="whiteColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource blueColor}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource whiteColor}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Style` tag must always specify the `TargetType`. So if, for instance, your style targets labels, you would have to change your code to:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource blueColor}" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource whiteColor}"/>
</Style>
```

By the way, the Xamarin.Forms previewer is a pain in the a**. The error message you're getting probably won't go away even after you fixed it. I had to do a complete clean & rebuild, then open the previewer for a different page, close it and open it again for the page I wanted before it would display anything.

You may be better off not using it.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue could be is that you have some code in the App.xaml.cs in the App() constructor that could be causing the issue as well.  For instance I fixed a problem in some code that I inherited that was trying to connect to a database so I fixed it like this:

```
        public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

    // connect to database code here
```

You can use DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled to determine if you are running in the designer or elsewhere.  You may also want to check your constructors in your xaml.cs files and see if they are trying to run any code that would cause the designer to throw that exception as well.

Comment: Works for other pages too.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having an issue with this, what fixed it for me is going to my NuGet package manager and updating Xamarin Forms to the latest version.

Instantly fixed the issue for me.

Good luck!